# Functor of points definition of a space modeled on a site

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, sheaf-theory, topos-theory

I'm trying to find a definition of a space modeled on a site which is: (i) plausible and natural in the context of general sites (ii) subsumes common examples.

Let $(C,J)$ be a grothendieck site and $Sh(C,J)$ the corresponding sheaf topos. Let $P$ be a property of morphisms in $C$ which containes all isomorphisms and is stable under composition and pullbacks. **The aim is to define a space as a $J$-sheaf with a cover by representable sheaves that glue by $P$ morphisms.**

> **Definition 1:** A **"nice"** $P$-local space is a sheaf $F \in Sh(C,J)$ s.t. there exists a representable sheaf $h_U$ and an epimorphism $\varphi: h_U \to F$ satisfying the following:
>
> - $\varphi: h_U \to F$ is representable and has property $P$ (meaning all pullbacks to representable sheaves have property $P$).

**Example 1:** If $C= Aff$, $J=Zariski$ and $P=\text{open immersion}$, we get a a scheme.

**Example 2:** If $C=Aff$, $J= \text{etale}$ and $P= \text{etale}$ we get an algebraic space (I hope. Separability conditions for algebraic spaces vary so I'm not so sure about the conventions here).

**Example 3:** If $C= \text{CartSp}$, $J = \text{open immersion}$ and $P =C^{k}$ we get a $C^k$-manifold.

Here is the wierd part. The definition above (although rather natural) only gives us some subcategory of "nice" schemes/algebraic spaces.

> **Question 1:** What subcategory of schemes does **Example 1** correpond to? If I require that the covers be finite coproducts of affine scheme do I get qcqs schemes?

To get the category of schemes we need an extra step:

> **Definition 2:** A **general** $P$-local space is a sheaf $F \in Sh(C,J)$ s.t. there exists a representable sheaf $h_U$ and an
> epimorphism $\varphi: h_U \to F$ satisfying:
>
> - $h_U \times_F h_U$ is a **"nice"** $P$-local space.
> - Both projections $\pi_i : h_U \times_F h_U \to h_U$ are representable by a $P$ morphism.
>
> **Question 2:** Is the above condition equivalent to requiring that the
> diagonal $h_U \to h_U \times h_U$ be representable by a separated
> $P$-local space?

Now wer'e fine since any intersection of affines is a quasi-affine scheme which satisfies **definition 1.**

> **Question 3:** Why is this step reasonable from this point of view? Does this have something to do with closure under pullbacks? Does "definition 1" generate "definition 2" by taking arbitrary pullbacks?.

Comment: [My thesis](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~zll22/thesis.pdf) is all about this idea. Your examples are not quite correct. For instance, in (1) you should ask for local isomorphisms, not open immersions; and even then you only get quasicompact semiseparated schemes.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thanks! Could you please try to summarize the relavant part of your thesis here? In particular what is the natural definition of a (qcqs scheme)/algebraic space in this setting?

Comment: I can copy the summary that's already in there, but it's not quite self-contained... as for qcqs schemes, see Example 3.5.22(iii). (Replace finitely presented algebras with general algebras to remove the lfp condition.)

Comment: @ZhenLin I'm trying to collect the relevant parts from your thesis and It looks like it could take me a considerable amount of time. I would be very greatful and accept your answer if you'd write one summarizing the relevant points to answer my question. What I'm looking for is simplest and naive functor definition of a (qcqs) scheme/algebraic space which I can work with in practice. Thanks.

Comment: Very well. I'm afraid what I wrote does not answer any of the questions in the post, however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First things first: we have to define what open immersions are. (!) We take for granted some class of basic open immersions – in the case of schemes, the ones corresponding to principal localisations of rings – and then close under unions and descent. (Making this precise is rather complicated if one wants to be general.)

Once we know what open immersions are, we can define local isomorphisms: these are the morphisms $X \to Y$ for which there is a cover of $X$ by open immersions $U \to X$ such that the composite $U \to X \to Y$ is also an open immersion. This is a completely straightforward generalisation of the definition of local homeomorphism.

Finally, we can define "spaces": these are the sheaves $Y$ for which there is an epimorphic local isomorphism $X \twoheadrightarrow Y$ where $X$ is a disjoint union of representable sheaves. This actually gives all schemes – to cut down to qcqs schemes, simply restrict to finite unions everywhere.

As far as I know, there is no shortcut that completely avoids the notion of local isomorphism. Demazure and Gabriel simply unfold the definition of local isomorphism into the definition of scheme.

Comment: Open immersion can be defined as etale+monic I think. Thanks! That actually makes sense. In the definition of a local isomorphism $X$ is a possibly non-representable sheaf with a representable epimorphic zariski open cover correct? If so this is exactly the "Definition 1" in my question.

Comment: Yes, étale monomorphisms are open immersions. But now you have to define not-necessarily-representable étale morphisms. Also any representable open immersion in your sense is guaranteed to be a monomorphism, so it is not the same as local isomorphism.

Comment: @ZhenLin do you not get all schemes as colimits of representable sheaves(not presheaves!) over (small) diagrams consisting only of open immersions?

Comment: Every scheme can be expressed as such a colimit but not all such colimits are schemes. (For instance, consider the coequaliser of two distinct automorphisms of a scheme.)